# Are there any plans to migrate poker questions to poker.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

I sort of assume that this is all in hand by TPTB, but it would be nice to have confirmation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Migrations to and from beta sites are discouraged *anyway*; migrations of on-topic questions to other sites where they might be on-topic are even less popular.

And [as bwarner notes](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/686/1106), doing so could unbalance a site that's already a bit... iffy.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should first make sure that the Poker site can stand on its own.  Shotgunning a bunch of already answered questions over there isn't going to do them any favors, and will cause confusion if the site doesn't survive.  Once it looks to be in a stable place, it would probably make sense to migrate questions to that site.

As a corollary, it is my understanding that poker questions are still on-topic here, though it would certainly be encouraged to ask them at the Poker site instead.